# Transition text of a div by clicking an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

VERY new to js but here it goes.

I want to be able to click on one of the images in the Portfolio section and have it change the text of the h3 in the Text section with a fade transition as well as select the corresponding slide in the slider.

Code:

```
<!-- 960 Container -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- Description -->
    <div class="sixteen columns">

        <!-- Text -->
            <h3 class="page_headline">Why Do You Need Manage+ For Your Business?</h3>

        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">

                <li>
                <div id="details">Tier-1 Tech Support</div>
                </li>

                <li>
                <div id="details">Off-site Backups</div>
                </li>

                <li>
                <div id="details">Loaner Computer</div>
                </li>

             </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End Description-->

    <!-- Portfolio Content -->
    <div id="portfolio-wrapper">

        <!-- 1/4 Column -->
        <div class="four columns portfolio-item">
                <div class="item-img"><a href="support.html"><img src="img/support.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="overlay link"></div></a></div>
                <div class="portfolio-item-meta">
                    <h4><a href="support.html">Tier-1 Tech Support</a></h4>
                </div>
        </div>

        <!-- 1/4 Column -->
        <div class="four columns portfolio-item">
                <div class="item-img"><a href="backup.html"><img src="img/backup.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="overlay link"></div></a></div>
                <div class="portfolio-item-meta">
                    <h4><a href="backup.html">Off-site Backups</a></h4>
                </div>
        </div>

        <!-- 1/4 Column -->
        <div class="four columns portfolio-item">
                <div class="item-img"><a href="loaner.html"><img src="img/loaner.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="overlay link"></div></a></div>
                <div class="portfolio-item-meta">
                    <h4><a href="loaner.html">Loaner Computer</a></h4>
                </div>
        </div>



    </div><!-- End Portfolio Content -->

</div><!-- End 960 Container -->
```

Comment: Please show us the code you've already tried.

Comment: OP edited with more focused question and current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is plane javascript or for lesser code, jquery.

just place your img and your div in the markup and bind the click event of the img to function in which you toggle your division display

you can have multiple images, referring to multiple containers(or same containers), which are hidden by default, but as you click on the relative image, it would appear.

see the code below

create your markup like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image">
        <img src='../images/actions_button_ok.png' data-target="one" />
        <img src='../images/actions_button_ok.png' data-target="two" />
        <img src='../images/actions_button_ok.png' data-target="three" />
   </div>
        <div class="target" id="one" >
           this is text A
        </div>
        <div class="target" id="two" >
           this is text B
        </div>
        <div class="target" id="three" >
           this is text C
        </div>
  </div>
```

and your jquery code as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').on("click",function(){
       $('.target').hide();
       $('#'+$(this).data('target')).toggle(1000);
    });    
});
```

basically, your html structure can be of your choice, but that's how you should go about it.
explore more about jquery.

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/V9QyU/2/).

instead of binding click to img, you can bind it to your li aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I be able to do something like this with different images changing the text of the target div?

Comment: If you would like a visual of what I am attempting please follow http://www.test.pcmanhq.com/manage+.html

Comment: Thank you Manish for your quick responses and patience. I don't think my OP was succinct enough to express my situation adequately. I just edited it as well as my code. Please review if I haven't worn down your patience just yet :)